# In android Custom View How can i style my Custom View programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I have a Custom View "CustomLayout" subclass of RelativeLayout.

```
public class CustomLayout extends RelativeLayout implements View.OnClickListener{
private String titleText;
private Context context;
private AttributeSet attrs;
private ImageView iv1,iv2;
private TextView title,tv2;
private TextView textView;
private Button button;


public CustomLayout(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}
public CustomLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context = context;
    this.attrs = attrs;
    init();

}
public CustomLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    this.context = context;
    this.attrs = attrs;
    initAttributes(context,attrs,defStyle);
}
 private void initAttributes(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    // declare styleable here to programatically set custom view style attributes
    final int[] styleable = new int[] {
            android.R.attr.src,
            android.R.attr.textAppearance,
            android.R.attr.text,
            android.R.attr.textSize
    };
    Arrays.sort(styleable);

    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, styleable, defStyleAttr,0);
    ...
}
```

I don't know how to set the properties pro-grammatically by passing arguments in the last constructor ,which takes three arguments, from my Activity. I know to do it from layout.xml file as shown in code below.Please help

```
 <com.example.customview.CustomLayout
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
    app:titleText="HappyTrips Editors"
    app:descriptText="@string/content"
    app:titleTextColor="#FF0000"
    app:descriptTextColor="#0000FF"
    app:titleTextSize="8sp"
    app:descriptTextSize="6sp"
    app:bgColor="#FFFF00"/>
```

In my ListAdapter

```
 @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View result=convertView;
    if (convertView==null){
        result=inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_list_items,null);
        CustomLayout object = (CustomLayout)result.findViewById(R.id.view1);
```

How to pass arguments containing AttributeSet in CustomLayout constructor from here

Answer (score 2):

in layout.xml you can user style,it will work  or
CustomLayout object=new CustomLayout(new ContextThemeWrapper(this,R.style,customStyle));